# Why does the number of filters does not determine the output size in the CNN layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, transposed-convolution

The formula to determine the output size is **[(W−K+2P)/S]+1**. Here the number of filters used is not significant for determining the ouput size, I was wondering why?

Is it because Each filter is separately applied to the input to obtain a feature map and the output of the that part is considered as dimension size?

Please note:

- **W** refers to the **input size**, **K** refers to the **filter size** where as **P** stands for
  **padding** and **S** stands for **stride**

Comment: Can you please define the variables?  Not all people use the same letters for these parameters.

Comment: Updated the question with terms explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you've given is for 1 filter. If you have $N$ filters, then you have $N$ outputs of the size you describe.